# How do I remove the category title on category pages for Magento 2?

Tags: category, magento-2.1.8

I am trying to remove the category title on category pages on Magento 2.1.8. I got this page  vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml and removed this-

```
 <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading</argument>
            <argument name="add_base_attribute_aria" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading toolbar-amount</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Rss\Link" name="rss.link" template="Magento_Catalog::category/rss.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
```

I took that file and added it to `app/design/frontend/mytheme/theme/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

I cleaned and flushed the cache and it didn't work. So I did a little bit of research and came across this-

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220806/magento2-how-can-override-vendor-module-catalog-to-magento-default-theme`

and it recommended putting it in this folder

`app/design/frontend/mytheme/theme/Magento_Catalog/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

I tried that, flushed and cleaned the cache and still nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can't just delete the code. I kept the code in there and added `<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>` and it removed it.

Comment: You can also accept your own answer to close this :)

Comment: in my case it is: <referenceContainer name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>

Answer (score 0):

To override inside a vendor module, the layout should be placed in

> app/design/frontend/mytheme/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

Make sure you clear your cache etc.

Comment: Just tried-app/design/frontend/mytheme/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml and it still didn't work. I have overrides in my theme that work fine, it is just this one that is being a pain.